# Is it possible to get item id by host ip using one zabbix api?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I would like to get 'itemid' by item.get api, and filter it by host **ip**

I tried this request, but it doesn't work (works only when giving host id):

{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "item.get",
"params": {
"output": "extend",
"selectInterfaces":["ip"],
"search": {
"ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
},
"auth": "038e1d7b1735c6a5436ee9eae095879e",
"id": 1
}

Any idea for me pls?

Comment: The interface is part of the host, not the item. You need to use item.get() to fetch hostids, then get interfaces with host.get(), then filter by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want the item id of a specific item key/name from an host with specific ip address.

You can do a `hostinterface.get` with a filter for the required ip address, to obtain the `hostid`.
Then you can do a `item.get` passing the `hostid` and a filter for the item key or name to get the `itemid`.

Comment: Thank you for replynig !
there is no way to do it by one api request?

Comment: It should be, but it's highly inefficient: a single `item.get` with key/name filter and `selectInterfaces` will return an object with all the matching items. You'll need to cycle through the returned interfaces to find the correct ip.